# facebook - add "user is using myapp"

Tags: facebook

is there any way how can I add on user's wall something like text "(User's name) started using my app."? Or does it show facebook automatically on user's wall when user allows permissions for myapp? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be automatically posted to the activity sidebar when using a non-sandboxed app with a non-test user account.